# PS Script for retrieving all sp designer 2010/2013 workflows from sp 2013 farm

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

i am looking for some help in regards to a ps script to fetch spd 2010/2013 workflows from sp2013 on prem.
Can someone please help with ps, i would like to export it to a csv file if possible

Answer (score 0):

This script can report all the OOTB workflows as well as SPD workflows. Please note that, this script cannot identify site workflows.

Script:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)  
{  
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"  
}  

$results = @()  
$siteColl =  "http://sharepoint.starkindustries.com/it"  

$site = Get-SPSite -Identity $siteColl -Limit All  
try  
{   
    foreach ($myWeb in $site.AllWebs)  
    {  
        Write-Host "Looking in Web: " $myWeb.Url -ForegroundColor Red  
        foreach($list in $myWeb.Lists)  
        {  
            if ($list.WorkflowAssociations -eq $true)  
        {  
            Write-Host $list.Title -ForegroundColor Blue  
            foreach ($wflowAssociation in $list.WorkflowAssociations)  
            {  
                $RowDetails =  @{            
                  "List Name"         = $wflowAssociation.ParentList.Title  
                  "Workflow Name"     = $wflowAssociation.InternalName  
                  "Running Instances" = $wflowAssociation.RunningInstances  
                  "Created On"        = $wflowAssociation.Created  
                  "Modified On"       = $wflowAssociation.Modified  
                  "Parent Web"        = $wflowAssociation.ParentWeb  
                  "Task List"         = $wflowAssociation.TaskListTitle  
                  "History List"      = $wflowAssociation.HistoryListTitle                   
                }  

                $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $RowDetails  
            }            
        }  

    }  
}  

$myFileName = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\workflowList.csv"  
$results | Select-Object "List Name", "Workflow Name", "Running Instances", "Created On","Modified On","Parent Web", "Task List","History List"    | export-csv -Path $myFileName -NoTypeInformation  

}  

catch   
{   
    $e = $_.Exception   
    $line = $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber   
    $msg = $e.Message   
    Write-Host –ForegroundColor Red "Caught Exception: $e at $line"   
    Write-Host $msg   
    Write-Host "Something went wrong"  
}   

Write-Host " === === === === === Completed! === === === === === === == "
```

If you need to iterate all site collections in the farm just add one more foreach statement.

[Link to article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/find-all-workflows-in-sharepoint-using-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks Raf for sharing this, I did come across this article, unfortunately, its exporting an empty csv file plus it only exports sp2010 workflows not 2013 based on the comments I saw.

Comment: Do you have Workflow Manager configured in your organization?

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement, since 2013 Workflows are registered as subscriptions to Workflow Manager, that is not technically a part of SharePoint 2013 farm but a standalone component.

Please refer following PowerShell to enumerate throughout all Web Applications and generates the list of all 2013 Workflows in the SharePoint 2013 Farm and export it as a CSV file in your computer:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {

  Add-PSSnapin 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell'

}

CLS

$spAssignment = Start-SPAssignment

$outputFile = 'D:\Temp\2013Workflows.csv'

$output = '';

$wfResults = @();

$i = 0;

Write-Host 'Searching 2013 Workflows ....' -NoNewline;

 

# Get All Web Applications

$WebApps = Get-SPWebApplication

foreach($webApp in $WebApps) {

  # Get All Site Collection

  foreach ($spSite in $webApp.Sites)    {

    # get the collection of webs

    foreach($spWeb in $spSite.AllWebs) {

      $wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($spWeb)

      $wfsService = $wfm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()

      foreach ($spList in $spWeb.Lists) {

        $subscriptions = $wfsService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($spList.ID)

        foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {

          #$subscriptions.name

          #$subscriptions.PropertyDefinitions#._UIVersionString #_IsCurrentVersion

          $i++

          #excluding multiple version of the same workflow

          if (($spWeb.Url + $spList.Title + $subscriptions.Name) -ne $output) {

            $output = $spWeb.Url + $spList.Title + $subscription.Name   

            $wfID = $subscription.PropertyDefinitions["SharePointWorkflowContext.ActivationProperties.WebId"]       

            $wfResult = New-Object PSObject;

            $wfResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name 'URL' -value ($spWeb.URL);

            $wfResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name 'ListName' -value ($spList.Title);

            $wfResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name 'wfName' -value ($subscription.Name);

            $wfResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name 'wfID' -value ($wfID);

            $wfResults += $wfResult;

          }

          if ($i -eq 10) {Write-Host '.' -NoNewline; $i = 0;}

        }

      }

    }

  }

}

$wfResults | Export-CSV $outputFile -Force -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host

Write-Host 'Script Completed'

Stop-SPAssignment $spAssignment
```

Reference:

https://sharepointpixels.wordpress.com/2016/06/23/sharepoint-list-of-2013-workflows/

Comment: Thanks Julie for sharing, unfortunately it does not work. I am seeing 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.' plus access is denied errors.

Comment: Have you changed the $outputFile location in the script? Per my test this works well, please also make sure you have all the permission at all web applications.